# Brackets instead of comma using foreach to create JSON with PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, file, filesize

So I'm trying to create an open source file manager with php using ajax requests and, when i use json_encode my json response gets a close bracket for each array key.

This is the code (PHP):

```
<?php

$fileDirectory = "files/";
$fileArray = array_slice(scandir("$fileDirectory"), 3);
$fileSizeArray = array();

foreach($fileArray as $File){
    $fileSizeArray[$File] = filesize($fileDirectory.$File);
}

foreach($fileSizeArray as $File => $fileSize){
    echo json_encode ([
        $filesResponseArray[] = array(
            'fileName' => $File,
            'fileSize' => $fileSize
        )
    ]);
}
```

and this is the result:

```
[{"fileName":"61177d35527fd_w68FQFb.png","fileSize":10752}][{"fileName":"611780a39307c_1152265.jpg","fileSize":1383556}]
```

and i need this result

```
[{"fileName":"61177d35527fd_w68FQFb.png","fileSize":10752},{"fileName":"611780a39307c_1152265.jpg","fileSize":1383556}]
```

Comment: You must put everything into one big array and then encode all of it once, at the end. Otherwise you end up with lots of separate JSON structures

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You encode to quickly. Try this:

```
<?php

$fileDirectory = "files/";
$fileArray = array_slice(scandir("$fileDirectory"), 3);
$fileSizeArray = array();

foreach($fileArray as $File){
    $fileSizeArray[$File] = filesize($fileDirectory.$File);
}

foreach($fileSizeArray as $File => $fileSize){
        $filesResponseArray[] = array(
            'fileName' => $File,
            'fileSize' => $fileSize
        );
}

echo json_encode($filesResponseArray);
```

Comment: It's worked, just needed to add a semi-colon in $filesResponseArray, thanks!

Comment: @JoaoPedroCovreeSilva Nice! Ah, yes, I didn't notice that, I'll correct it.